# how to get from(sender) mail address in Compose mail window in outlook 2010 having MultiAccount using c#?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

i am developing outlook addin using c#.i have two accounts in the name of aaa@mydomain.com and bbb@mydomain.com.aaa@mydomain.com is default.But i have create a compose mail at that time i will change from address from aaa@mydomain.com into bbb@mydomain.com.

But i try to get from user mailid,it will be aaa@mydomain.com.

i already tried the below code.but it gives default account id.

```
Outlook.Accounts accounts = oApp.Application.Session.Accounts;
```

but i need what i want to get means.selected in composemail from field id.How to achieve it.

note :i am using outlook 2010 and 2013.

Thanks

Sanju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to read the MailItem.SendUsingAccount property?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have the account added. If you are just sending on behalf of another Exchange user, see the MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property.